# SQL Query: Get those orders that have products greater than 1

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions, having-clause

[image: Orders Table]

`psa_psofk` is order ID and `psa_prdfk` is product ID. I want only those orders that have more than one product i.e I don't want order 1 and 5.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh with notable exceptions :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select psa_psofk 
from mytable 
group by psa_psofk 
having count(*) > 1
```

This assumes no duplicates `(psa_psofk, psa_prdfk)`. Else, you need to change the `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct psa_prdfk) > 1
```

If you want entire rows, then one option uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.psa_psofk = t.psa_psofk and t1.psa_prdfk <> t.psa_prdfk
)
```

Comment: But I don't want to group my orders. I want exact same table without first and last row

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is query that returns number of orders those have products greater then 1

```
SELECT * FROM orders o INNER JOIN products p ON o.product_id = p.id 
WHERE o.product_id IN(SELECT o.product_id FROM orders o GROUP BY o.product_id  
HAVING COUNT(o.product_id) > 1)
```